# activate background tab

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm creating an addon using the Firefox Addon API (aka jetpack), and I would like to be able to switch to an inactive tab using the addon (ie. I can click a button in the addon and it would switch to an existing open tab). I would have assumed that it would be in the sdk/tabs package, but it doesn't seem to be there.

Comment: You can activate a tab using [sdk/tabs activate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/tabs#activate%28%29) indeed.

Comment: @matagus D'oh. I had thought that I had examined it pretty closely, but it looks like I missed that. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

for a non-sdk version, or even something you can use in sdk. if you have tab. set gBrowser.selectedTab = tabToSelect; and it will select it